# Почему нужно получить родителский элемент для добавления элемента рядом с ним?

Tags: javascript

Объясните мне пожалуйста, почему и зачем в этой задаче я получаю родителя кнопки?

Дан инпут. Рядом с ним находится кнопочка "+". По нажатию на эту кнопку под нашим инпутом должен появится еще один пустой инпут.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', func);

function func() {
  var parent = button.parentElement;
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');
  parent.appendChild(newInput);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="+" id="button">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: как узнать на какой елемент добавить инпут? Ответ: на тот который находиться кнопка. На каком елементе находиться кнопка? Ответ: на родительском

Comment: <input type="submit" value="+" id="button">   Очень сомнительно. Submit не для этого нужен.

Answer (score 0):

var parent = button.parentElement; ?????? (parentElement) <--- Из за этого конечно. parentElement выберает родительский элемент.

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', func);
function func() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('my-bl');
    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    parent.appendChild(newInput);
}

<div id="my-bl">
    <button id="button">+</button>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос ещё раз прочитайте, внимательно.

Comment: AppendChild добавляет в конец выбранного блока. Выбираешь род. блок и делаешь appendChild и все!

Comment: Если не выбрать определенный блок то он не знает куда добавлять. А твой блок здесь род. блок. Понятно?

Answer (score 0):

> Объясните мне пожалуйста, почему и зачем в этой задаче я получаю родителя кнопки?

Надо знать куда добавлять "детей", в этом случае, кто как не родительский элемент, знает своих детей.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', func);

function func() {
  var parent = button.parentElement;
  console.log(parent.tagName); //Body
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');
  parent.appendChild(newInput);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="+" id="button">
<input type="text">
```

[Док parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)